# Fractions and Fractional Numbers

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, formation-of-numbers, number-property

Using fractions and fractional numbers of the digits $1$ to $10$ and only the mathematical operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, including parenthesis (e.g. $1 + 2 - (3 * 4)$), can you write $11$ equations to get the numbers $0$ to $10$ (one number per equation)?

###### Rules

- Each equation must use **ALL** the digits from $1$ to $10$ but **ONLY ONCE**.
- Fractions and fractional numbers **cannot** result in integers when evaluated individually. For example, in the case of this puzzle,  $\frac{3}{9}$ is considered a valid fraction but $\frac{9}{3}$ is not since it evaluates to $3$. A valid fractional number in the context of this puzzle contains a fraction like $\frac{8}{3}$ or $\frac{9}{7}$ etc.
- Each equation *as written* must show the fractions or fractional numbers.
- No concatenation.

Thus the LHS of each equation will show five fractions or fractional numbers. RHS would be from $0$ to $10$ ― so eleven equations. All $10$ digits must be used but only once.

---

No partial answers please and no programming.

Comment: "Digits 1 to 10" means "numbers 1 to 10", right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You say the LHS will contain 5 fractions, so does that mean we cannot use for example 1/(2+3) or (4+5)/6 ?

Comment: Correct @JaapScherphuis. Five seperate fractions using all 1 to 10 only once.

Comment: 10 is not a digit. The ten digits that exist are 0-9.

Comment: Can infinitely repeating fractions (e.g. $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3}$) be treated as one instance of their repeating sequence (e.g. $0.\overline{3}$ becomes just $0.3$)? If not, what should we consider as the cutoff? For example, my calculator stops at 16 decimal places for $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Must *all* operators be used, or is simply alternating between addition and subtraction allowed?

Comment: Any operators mentioned. Multiple times OK

Comment: Interesting; I wonder how high one still can get all (much higher than 10).

Comment: @Taco as you can see from the answer below, you do not have to go to multiple decimals for fractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technique I found helpful was

> to get groups of 3 and 2 fractions yielding small integers, and then combine those. For 2, we need things broadly like odd/2 + even/4. For 3, we need things broadly like .../2 + .../3 + .../6.

First of all, notice that

> 9/2 + 4/3 + 7/6 = 7 ... (1)
>  (9/2 + 4/3) / (7/6) = 5 ... (1')
>  1/5 + 8/10 = 1 ... (2)
>  8/10 / (1/5) = 4 ... (2')

From these

> we can get 5-4=1, 7-4=3, 5-1=4, 7-1=5, 5+1=6, 7/1=7, 7+1=8, 5+4=9. So we still need 0, 2, 10.

Now tweak (1) and (2) by swapping two numerators and fixing up:

> 9/2 + 1/3 + 7/6 = 6 ... (3)
>  4/5 - 8/10 = 0 ... (4)

which

> by multiplying gets us 0. Now we need 2, 10.

A similar switcheroo gets us

> 1/2 + 4/3 + 7/6 = 3 ... (5)
>  9/5 - 8/10 = 1 ... (6)

from which

> we get 2 by subtraction. So now we just need 10.

This one we get in a slightly different way. (Maybe there's an easier way, but this is the first thing I found.)

> (9/2 + 7/3) x (6/4) = 41/4 = 10+1/4 ... (7)
>  (10/8) x (1/5) = 1/4 ... (8)
>  so subtracting these yields 10

and we're done.

Comment: nice approach in little pieces.